# Adding Double-quotations to Perl Stashed Term in HTML Search Bar

Tags: html, perl

I would like to add double quotations around a stashed perl term within my input value for "q".

```
<form method="get" action="https://scholar.google.com/scholar?hl=en&q=ascr%238&btnG=&as_sdt=1%2C33&as_sdtp=">
<input name="q" type=“search” size=“60” value=&quot;[%name%]&quot> 
<input type="submit" name="sa" value=Search />
</form>
```

The output I receive is - "name, rather than "name".

If I swap out [%name%] with a normal string then there are double quotes.

Anyone know how to fix this problem, other than getting a new stashed term?

Apologies in advance for my small vocabulary -_-

Answer (score 2):

First of all, I'm going to assume that's a Template-Toolkit template.

It's very hard to tell what you want. I think you want one of the following:

```
value="[% name | html %]"                name: John Smith => value: John Smith

value="&quot;[% name | html %]&quot;"    name: John Smith => value: "John Smith"
```

Comment: thanks! That led me on the right track.

value=&quot;[% name | html %]"     did the trick

Comment: yes, the latter is what I wanted. Thanks for the help!